# TaskCanceledException on Start-ComplianceSearch

Tags: azure, powershell, auditing, o365security-compliance

I'm at my wits end with this one. I'm trying to start a compliance search in the Microsoft Compliance Center and I'm running into this error.

```
Creating SearchA task was canceled.
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Start-ComplianceSearch], TaskCanceledException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=BL2NAM02WS018,RequestId=3311342e-a545-4a5f-9fa1-2e9999b0d901,TimeStamp=6/5/2019 7:49:02 PM] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-TaskCanceledException] 821
   CC486,Microsoft.Office.ComplianceJob.Tasks.StartComplianceSearch
    + PSComputerName        : nam02b.ps.compliance.protection.outlook.com
```

It's pretty simple code, I'm just doing this...

```
Start-ComplianceSearch -Identity "Test Search Name" -Force
```

I've verified I created the search correctly in compliance center (via Powershell), and I can run it from the UI.

Anyone have any ideas where to start debugging this? Any help is much appreciated!!!

Comment: Since I really don't know the answer, I will ask the dumb question. Do you have the Mailbox Search role assigned to your account? You should be able to see that from `get-managementroleassignment -RoleAssignee "<your account>"`. I "think" the command would not even be available to you if you didn't have permission, but I haven't been in that situation. It is probably some backend issue on Microsoft's side.

Comment: Not a dumb question, I've run into the permissions thing a few times. I've verified the ID we are using has eDiscovery, Org Admin, and I believe Compliance Admin (one of the compliance roles).

Comment: Has this type of use case ran successfully in your past? Just for sanity check, see if you have someone who has the AAD GlobalAdmin privs to give it a shot, at least once. Also. your post appears to have some PII you may want to sanitize out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments above.

This just magically worked today. I think the Google search results that said internal Azure Error ended up being correct.

If anyone else hits this, just one other thing that may have caused this other than an Azure hiccup. You can only have 3 sessions going to the Security and Compliance Center at one time. We may have had some hung PowerShells running the in the background that would have increased our session count past 3.

TL;DR - This an Azure internal error. Report it to Microsoft.